# Get an objects value by accessing and matching it's key value

Tags: javascript

I am retrieving an object with a database call, I want to access a key's value by matching that key with a variable that I have.

In my database return I get an object that looks similar to this:

```
{"_id":"5c840d548a7db8af2f9eefea",
"domain":"chatbotdemo.com","deliveryTime":"ba",
"emailAddress":"ab","freeDelivery":"ab","onSale":"ab"}
```

I have a variable:

```
var intent = 'emailAddress'
```

The variable should always exist but theres a very slight chance it may not
and it may also be null.

What I want to do is access the value from that key field that matches the var intent, or at least get the key value pair.

What I also want to do is then if it is null then call an error, my full code is below:

```
getClientsDialog: function (domain, intent, callback) {

    MongoClient.connect('mongodb://111011001101101', function (err, client) {
        if (err) throw err;
        var db = client.db('10001101');
        db.collection('dialog').findOne({ domain: domain}, function (err, doc) {

    // here I would want to say if (!err && ****logic to check match****)
            if (!err) {

                callback(doc)
            } else {
                throw err;
                callback(err)
            }
            client.close();
        });
        console.dir("Called findOne");
    });
```

}

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!!

Comment: `object[key]` => `value`.. (also, "the variable" *always* exists, the key to which refers to [by name] may not; and if there is no matching key then there is no matching pair); so, eg. `var intentValue = doc[intent]; ..`

Comment: You can use Object.keys() to get an array with keys. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys

Comment: Thanks user, I've been using Javascript for almost 2 years now professionally and until now I have not known that object[key] produces the value for that key! thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if i got the problem right but in ES6 you can use a [computed value as an property name](http://es6-features.org/#ComputedPropertyNames). Something like this:

```
let serverJson = {
    "_id":"5c840d548a7db8af2f9eefea",
    "domain":"chatbotdemo.com","deliveryTime":"ba",
    "emailAddress":"ab","freeDelivery":"ab","onSale":"ab"
};

let intent = "emailAddress";

if (serverJson[intent]!== undefined)  {

}
else {

}
```